# Restore SQL Server database from snapshot in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, smo

I have written a method which will restore a database from a backup file using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.

However, I can't see any way to restore a database from a snapshot programmatically. Does anyone know if there is a method for this?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.restore.aspx

Comment: Doesn't mention snapshots anywhere in that article.

Comment: That google search is useless. I already said I can restore a database programmatically. I'm talking specifically about snapshots.

Answer (score -1):

Call one of the Restore() methods for the snapshot.

Here is more Information:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee535523(v=office.14).aspx

how about this:

> RESTORE DATABASE { database | @database_name_var } 
>            FROM DATABASE_SNAPSHOT = database_snapshot This will restore the snapshot (to the same server/database/schema name.)

[Example:](http://ss64.com/sql/restore_snap.html)

```
USE master  
RESTORE DATABASE ss64Database FROM DATABASE_SNAPSHOT = 'ss64_snapshot01';
GO
```

Comment: Yes, I did see that article, but it is referring to sharepoint. I'm not writing a shrepoint app.

Comment: @tuseau: Added non-sharepoint version. You don't need SMO for either of this.